# Are numbers necessary for some config/rule file names?

Tags: configuration

In the tutorials/manuals, I often see numbers like this. Is it necessary? If so, specific numbers necessary?

> To make the setting persistent across reboot, one can use a udev rule:
>
> /etc/udev/rules.d/**69**-hdparm.rules

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/hdparm

Answer (score 5):

From `man udev` in `Rules Files` section:

> RULES FILES
>
> > The udev rules are read from the files located in the
> > system rules directories /usr/lib/udev/rules.d and
> > /usr/local/lib/udev/rules.d, the volatile runtime directory
> > /run/udev/rules.d and the local administration directory
> > /etc/udev/rules.d. All rules files are collectively sorted and
> > processed in lexical order, regardless of the directories in which
> > they live.

So the short answer is Yes, specially if you do care about the order in which the **udev rules** are processed.

Comment: I'd add in this good answer (regarding last question in OP) that since only lexical order is important, no *specific number* is required for a given rule. The associated filename only needs to start with a sequence of chars that will rank the rule as desired amongst the others. Numerals are just an handy way to manage the order. The latest rule to be executed is often named 99-whatever but could also well be named zz-whatever instead.

Comment: I implement a similar pattern to this for sourcing config/bash files which follows this quite common pattern.

`for f in $(find ~/.config/xxx/conf.d/ -maxdepth 1 -type f| sort); do source $f; done`

Comment: @MC68020 Very good point! I forgot to address that info in my answer but yours is actually good and complements my answer in a good way! Thanks

Comment: @Brad that's a good way to know the order in which the files are processed. Although udev rules cannot be sourced (they are not shell scripts) that's a good way to get the actual order and it's important for scripts which follows this rules of sorting. AFAIK the init deamon (when you (re)start,stop a service) are processed using something like this method.

Comment: @Brad btw using zsh you could show the files in a sorted way so you can avoid the use  of `sort`. (Untested) this might works `source "$(find ~/.config/xxx/conf.d/ -maxdepth 1 -type f| sort)"`

Comment: @EdgarMagallon - indeed -- I wasn't suggesting to source the udev files, just giving a similar example. This pattern is used so often in unix. My use case was that I decided to break out my complex and overly long `.zshrc` into sub-files to make them more manageable. I use this method to source the sub rc files from the main rc file.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon, no `source file1 file2` sources `file1` with `file2` in `$1`. You want `for f (~/.config/xxx/conf.d/*(N.)) . $f`. Using `find` that way doesn't make sense

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas oh, thanks! I haven't been able to test that so I was not sure it it'd work or not. That code is for zsh, isn't that? For `bash`, is there a way to use glob qualifiers? (For sorting data like zsh does)

Comment: @EdgarMagallon, glob qualifiers are zsh-only. But here, the glob qualifiers are `N` for nullglob and `.` as the equivalent of `-type f`. Sorting is lexical by default like in every shell, though you could also use the `n` glob qualifier for numeric sorting (for `12_foo.conf` to come after `2_bar.conf` for instance)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks so much! I was wrong and also I was thinking `N` was used for sorting. Thanks for the clarification.